# Click link to a new page, change class on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a set of 3 tabs on my homepage. The one with the class of "current" is the one that is shown.

How would be able to link from pageX to my homepage, and tell it which tab to have open?

For example, if I click on the "Missions" link, I want it to go to the homepage, with the "Missions" tab shown (with "current" class).

I am using Ruby on Rails for this project. But I would prefer a jQuery/JavaScript solution.

Comment: you can use a hash value like `/myhome#missions` or a request param like `/myhome?view=missions` and then use javascript to add the class to the element

Comment: How can I get javascript to examine the hash of the current url?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hash value like `/myhome#missions` or a request param like `/myhome?view=missions` and then use javascript to add the class to the element

Using hash

```
jQuery(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        //based on the value of hash set the current tab
    }
})
```